# Why was my answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-answers

Regarding [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33467/among-the-gentiles-why-job-and-bilaam-were-recognized-as-prophets-whereas-muham) My answer was deleted on the spot and it does not satisfy any of the conditions mentioned in the linked article:

> Why was your post deleted? See the help center.

I have put the [answer here too](http://pastebin.com/076uP8ke), as you can see it is a valid answer to the question and does not satisfy the conditions of deletion mentioned above

Answer (score 6):

Far as I can see, you don't answer the question. One rabbi in one community accepting Islam means about as much as me accepting Islam, God forbid. By that Rationale, [Shabtai Zvi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabbatai_Zevi) is the Messiah.

You answered "Why don't jews accept Muhammed/Islam?" with "They should, look at this one guy who was ostracized for doing so! Ignore the fact that he contradicts Jewish law, and was not endorsed by even his own community, because reasons."

You are also drawing from a historical wikipedia article as a source to answer a question that pertains to Jewish law. That is effectively hearsay. You're other source is basically an Islamic midrash, lehavdil, so it has no credibility whatsoever on this site.

(You also antagonize Jewish Tradition in your answer, though that would be grounds for editing, rather than for deletion.)

Comment: "the collection of authentic historical traditions of Islam" is not how Jews usually refer to the Quran.

Comment: @BabySeal The Quran is about as "authentic" as the book of Mormon, the so called "new testament" the stories of Asgard, the stories of Olympus, ...